# Monitoring disk space

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-space

I am looking for an app like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) or [SpaceMonger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/) for Windows, preferably command line.

I want to set up a script to run regularly whcih will generate a report similar to what you see in WinDirStat with folders and percentage of space taken up.

So over the period of like a week or two I can see which areas/folders are fluctuating in size.

Answer (score 2):

- [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview) - looks like not supported much

[image]

- Maybe [TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I really like Space Sniffer.  It's reasonably fast to scan drives, and you can scan multiple drives simultaneously.  It apparently has some command line switches, but I doubt it would be very useful for automated scripts.
http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/tips_and_tricks.html

For command line, perhaps something like du would suit your needs?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx